# cx_freeze [Errno 2] No such file or directory problem

Tags: python, cx-freeze

When I try to use cx_freeze (python setup.py build), it creates the build, but at the bottom, I get the error message:

error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'D:\...\...\...\build\exe.win-amd64-3.9\lib\importlib\resources\abc.pyc'

The same error is displayed in the py file where the exe file was previously created normally.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.